eigenstate is missing in the solution of vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue API in qiskit==1.0
I am using an API result= vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue using different version of qiskit. The qiskit==0.46 gives eigenstate but theqiskit==1.0 donot give eigenstate.
The complete code with result using qiskit==0.46 is given in the Edit2 of question : Substitute for QuantumInstance in latest qiskit==1.0 and the modified code which can work on qiskit==1.0 is given in solution of the question as shown below: Substitute for QuantumInstance in latest qiskit==1.0
{   'aux_operators_evaluated': None,
    'cost_function_evals': 226,
    'eigenvalue': 0.3137722886474602,
    'optimal_circuit': <qiskit.circuit.quantumcircuit.QuantumCircuit object at 0x7f9dbf535f90>,
    'optimal_parameters': {   ParameterVectorElement(θ[0]): 3.726825317040346,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[1]): 4.923652575593262,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[2]): 2.1799494002461577,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[3]): 4.342309624592069,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[4]): 3.9943861870781547,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[5]): 2.525898173896921,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[6]): 6.4689779624478385,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[7]): 6.861702135664873,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[8]): 3.3363062351723034,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[9]): 0.4303643667680397,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[10]): 4.26867749230714,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[11]): 0.09306511001614937,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[12]): 3.638200155835128,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[13]): 4.595353264668222,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[14]): 1.1300128175140915,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[15]): 6.254355360432362,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[16]): 5.451784319298557,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[17]): 2.5615938491419166,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[18]): 3.0653255873701926,
                              ParameterVectorElement(θ[19]): 5.062189928072163},
    'optimal_point': array([3.72682532, 4.92365258, 2.1799494 , 4.34230962, 3.99438619,
       2.52589817, 6.46897796, 6.86170214, 3.33630624, 0.43036437,
       4.26867749, 0.09306511, 3.63820016, 4.59535326, 1.13001282,
       6.25435536, 5.45178432, 2.56159385, 3.06532559, 5.06218993]),
    'optimal_value': 0.3137722886474602,
    'optimizer_evals': None,
    'optimizer_result': <qiskit_algorithms.optimizers.optimizer.OptimizerResult object at 0x7f9dc752ee90>,
    'optimizer_time': 2.2629570960998535}

I am really not sure how to get the eigenstate now ?

If you think about it, it doesn't really make sense to give the eigenvector back: the whole point of VQE is that the vectors are too large to directly be dealt with.
However, if you want to build it, the VQEResult returns the optimal_point, which corresponds to the value of the optimal parameters. So, you only have to assign these parameters to your circuit and get the resulting Statevector out of it:
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

eigvec = Statevector(ansatz_opt.assign_parameters(result.optimal_point))

Note that it likely actually isn't an eigenvector of your Hamiltonian, since your VQE doesn't seem to converge: the optimal_value that you get doesn't match the minimal eigenvalue of Hamiltonian, which is around $0$.

Thank you @TristanNemoz.
